# UILabel moving left or right Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I have set up 2 text by autolayouts and constraints. Now i would like to move text 1 to the right and text 2 to the left but it didnt work. Both the text should end on the center of the view (horizontally)

```
@IBOutlet weak var Text1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Text2: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState],
                   animations: {
                    self.Text1.frame.origin.x += 300
                    self.Text2.frame.origin.x -= 300
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Did i did anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Don't update frame if you are using auto layout. It won't work at all.

Comment: how should i make it move without updating the frames yea?

Comment: Modify constraint constants not frames

Comment: I would suggest you to use stack view and embed these labels. Whenever you want to swap them remove the last and insert at index 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `CGAffineTransform(translationX: y:)` to achieve something like that:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
     self.breathingStatusLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.breathingStatusLabel.bounds.origin.x + 300, y: self.breathingStatusLabel.bounds.origin.y)
}, completion: nil)
```

To move it back to it's originial place add this in another animation block:

```
self.breathingStatusLabel.transform = .identity
```

**Note:** `CGAffineTransform(translationX: y:)` translates the view to a provided location but it doesn't change the frame of that. So be careful about that while using this, to just animate labels you can use it.

But for example you want to move `UITextFields` when keyboard appears, you should change the constraints if its `autolayout` or change its frame. If you use `CGAffineTransform(translationX: y:)` you will notice that it will move the  `UITextField` but when you tap on it nothing will work coz its frame didn't change, just the location changed.

Comment: This works almost as expected but if the length of text is big and text is clipped it don't show complete text it just moves the labe. What I want is to animate text so that if text is clipped it animates and user will be able to see whole text. Can you modify this ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with constraints of labels.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState],
               animations: {


     //here modify constraints constant or may need to add some new constraints dynamically.

           //     self.Text1.frame.origin.x += 300
           //     self.Text2.frame.origin.x -= 300
           //     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: so I am to comment off all the codes in there and replace with constraints?

Comment: of course, if you've give constraints in storyboards then you need to create `IBOutlet` and modify is constant in animation block. Or you can also set constraints programatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var Text1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Text1LeftConstrin:NSLayoutConstraint!
// (Connect this with your Text1 label left constrain)

@IBOutlet weak var Text2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Text1LeftConstrin:NSLayoutConstraint! 
//(Connect this with your Text1 label left constrain)

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState],
               animations: {
                Text1.constant += 300
                Text2.constant -= 300
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.transition(with:self.yourLabel,
  duration: 5.0,
  options: [.autoreverse,.repeat],
  animations: {
    self.yourLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: (-1 * (self.view.frame.size.width / 2) + 20), y:0)
    self.yourLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: ((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - 20), y:0)
  }, 
  completion: nil)
```